# How to manually add a user in ibm cloudant?

Tags: authentication, cloudant

I have a cloudant database with a lot of deleted docs. Since they can't be destroyed, I would like to make a filtered copy with the non deleted items to a temporary base, destroy the original one, and copy the temporary base to a fresh database with the same name as before.
The problem is when I destroy the base, the API keys generated are also destroyed...
So the front app calling the new base can't acces it !

I would like to manually create a user/password, so I can recreate the same user each time I destroy the database.
I don't know how to do it ?

Or is there another way to achieve my goal ??

Answer (score 3):

To answer your actual question, you can't add "users" to a Cloudant account, only databases. You can, however, make API-keys that span multiple databases, which sounds like it could be what you want:

https://dx13.co.uk/articles/2016/04/11/using-a-cloudant-api-key-with-multiple-cloudant-databases-and-accounts/

But as was noted by bessbd above, if your data model relies on document deletion, you're working against the grain of Cloudant, and sooner or later you'll end up with problems.

And finally -- the doc links appear to work just fine.

Maybe some useful stuff here: https://blog.cloudant.com/2019/11/21/Best-and-Worst-Practices.html

[disclaimer, I wrote that]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think it will solve my problem. 

But I still can't access to the page https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant?topic=cloudant-documents#tombstone-documents

Perhaps because I am in France, I get a french error message ?

Comment: I just clicked that link on my phone and it loads just fine, so while “it works for me” isn’t that helpful, it really seems to work from here (uk)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please expand a little further on your use case? Why do you want to get rid of the deleted docs? Is there a way to avoid deleting the docs? Also, have you already read https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/Cloudant?topic=cloudant-documents#tombstone-documents ?

Comment: The database is replicated to pouchdb on mobile. When there are many deleted documents, the replication when the user makes a fresh install takes a time that grows, grows...
Another problem is that the ibm docs links are broken. I can't acces to the page you mention.

Comment: Hi George, I don't think some of those docs are available in French. Can you try the english url or does it automatically convert to french?